# Highcharts layout cuts off last series after upgrade

Tags: highcharts

We were on version 2.0.4 prior up upgrading to latest. Our charts looked like this with even spacing and all the series shown correctly.

[image]

After upgrading and not making any changes, we are left with this image with the last series being cut thin and we are missing the last line.

[image]

We tried changing chart.marginBottom but it only made more empty space below what we saw. We aren't sure what needs to change for the newer v11.1

Comment: Can you send a simplified demo of this problem in the online editor? For example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sun57geh/

Comment: Yes, reproduced in https://jsfiddle.net/cag80tue/
We would like the line width to extend over the bottom axis instead of being half the width for the first 3 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `yAxis.min: -0.5;` and `yAxis.startOnTick: false;` to add space between the points and the begining of the yAxis.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wpd01ftn/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!